# Is it good to store data in JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that has about 50,000 users, but the question here is, is it good if I store data by Json file or not Because I'm currently doing this, but sometimes everything in JSON automatically deleted and The file becomes empty. i I don't know why, is JSON not dedicated to the huge amount of data Some examples of data that I store Like the ID of the server members, and also servers id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it good to store data in JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168797/is-it-good-to-store-data-in-json-file)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post duplicate questions. Your original question was closed as off-topic (opinion-based), and it's a very broad question. Without code, there's simply no way to know why you're losing data. And as far as storing in JSON... that's the opinion-soliciting part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with JSON file, is when multiple users try to edit the same information at the same time... you have to think about which update will persist... all except for one will get overwritten by the update that was last submitted.

Answer (score -2):

JSON is basically used to send and receive data from user and server, it is seldom used to store data, sometimes it does but not often.

For a dataset of 50k user consider using MySQL, it would be much easier to handle data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you posted is an opinion and not an objective answer. JSON is stored quite often. Also, MySQL is a relational database, which is not similar to JSON (where other database engines are natively JSON stores). The OP's question, though, is unclear - there's no telling why they're losing data, as no code is shown. Also note that the OP has now posted this question twice (their original was already closed as off-topic yesterday). Best to not answer off-topic questions.